# UserDefaults is not saving data after suddenly closing device

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

I am logging app and loading home page all task working properly. After login I save user data in UserDefaults. But if I suddenly close Apple TV then I am getting UserDefaults data as nil.

I am using this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isLogin")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

let apiToken = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "isLogin") as ? Bool
```

Comment: FYI - `let apiToken = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLogin")`. Do not use `value(forKey:` with `UserDefaults`. `value(forKey:)` is from `NSObject` and key-value coding.

Comment: UserDefaults do take a few seconds, so its not surprising that when you suddenly close app and the UserDefaults had saved some data at that moment it is not saving.

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLogin")